# segmentation fault while inserting into a set

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have written a sample program :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    set<int> myset[4];
    char *str[4]={"1-2-3-4","3-4-34-3","7-45-35-3","67-45466-3633-3"};

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
     char *data;
     strcpy(data,str[i]);
     char *pch;
      pch = strtok (data,"-");
              for(int j=0;pch != NULL&&j<4;j++)
              {
               myset[j].insert((int)strtol(pch, NULL, 10));
               pch = strtok (NULL, "-");
              }
    }  

getch();
return 0;   
}
```

This program gives a segmentation fault at

```
myset[j].insert((int)strtol(pch, NULL, 10));
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What does your debugger (e.g. `gdb` if on Linux) is telling you?

Comment: Oh, the tragedy of those who must use C... Please look at the `<string>` library facility in C++ to aid you in the writing of correct and readable code.

Comment: i am runnign this on windows in dev c++.The debugger says the fault is during the first insert into set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char *data;
strcpy(data,str[i]);
```

Tries to copy data to an unallocated pointer and causes an **Undefined Behavior**.
Your pointer should point to an allocated memory big enough to hold the data you are going to copy in to it.

The ideal solution is to use `std::string` and forget `char *` while programming in C++.

Comment: No while debugging the seg fault is during the first insert into the set.

Comment: @peter: The problem with Undefined Behavior is all bets are off and your program is allowed to show any random behavior,which is what you can see in this case.

Comment: @peter: Or it's in strtol, because you tried to use the data you tried to copy to an unitialized pointer. Trust Als, he's right.

Comment: as soon, as your code run into _undefined behavior_, everything can happen. It can _not crash_ at all, or crash _anywhere_ after that line.

Comment: I have changed the `char *data` to `char data[20]` as the length of the string will not be greater than 20.This is working fine.

Comment: @peter: Yes because the Undefined Behavior no longer exists now.`data` now has enough memory in which the string can be copied without invoking UB.I hope that convinces you.

Comment: @peter If you have `char data[20]`, make sure that the string will never be longer than *19* characters (because you have to count the null)

Answer (score 1):

you have to allocate data to be able to hold the copied string:

```
 char *data; //unallocated
 strcpy(data,str[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should produce the segfault there:

```
char *data;
     strcpy(data,str[i]);
```

Because you are copying Data to a place you did not allocate! If you like to do this "the c-way", you have to use `malloc`.

Or you dont use `char*,` use `std::string` instead! (and string.c_str() if you need a char*)

Comment: Err...`malloc`? in C++? Pray why? Why not `new`?

Comment: "new char", i have never read about that. If you start to use functions like "strcpy" you have to do the memory management, either with char[20] or with char* c = malloc(c, 20); I know it is bad for c++, but str* functions are too.

Comment: @AlokSave it would have to be `new[]`

Answer (score 1):

As you are copying the string in order to modify it with strtok you would need to use `std::vector<char>`

However strtok is not the ideal way to tokenise your string, and I would suggest a change of strategy.

You can, for example use `istringstream` to tokenise the string, which would enable you to read directly into an integer and then read a delimiter within your loop until you reach the end of the string.

`boost::tokenize` would do a lot of this work for you and you might want to consider using it.

By the way, whilst it still compiles to not break legacy code, you should never assign a literal to `char*`, but use `const char *`. On this occasion you are not making any attempt to modify them.